# Sonar project sub-modules

Tags: sonarqube

Is it possible to define sub-modules on a module in the sonar-project.properties?

My current config looks like this:

```
sonar.projectKey=project
sonar.projectName=project
sonar.projectVersion=1.0

sonar.branch=master
sonar.sources=.
sonar.language=php

# Available modules
sonar.modules=module1, module2

# Global source directory
sonar.sources=.
sonar.language=php

# Module1
module1.sonar.projectName=Module1
module1.sonar.projectBaseDir=path/module1

# Module2
module2.sonar.projectName=Module2
module2.sonar.projectBaseDir=path/module2
```

But the module1 has also sub-modules.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes it is possible...

```
sonar.projectKey=project
sonar.projectName=project
sonar.projectVersion=1.0

sonar.branch=master
sonar.sources=.
sonar.language=php

# Available modules
sonar.modules=module1, module2

# Global source directory
sonar.sources=.
sonar.language=php

# Module1
module1.sonar.projectName=Module1
module1.sonar.projectBaseDir=path/module1

module1.sonar.modules=subModule1

module1.subModule1.sonar.projectName=subModule1
module1.subModule1.projectBaseDir=path/subModule1

# Module2
module2.sonar.projectName=Module2
module2.sonar.projectBaseDir=path/module2
```

Comment: That's the more compact method and probably the easier one to manage, but you can also [put a properties file in each module](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScanner-Multi-moduleProject)

Comment: This link is no longer active.